# Testing nonlinearity in logistic regression (or other forms of regression)

Tags: regression, logistic, references, assumptions, regression-strategies

One of the assumption of logistic regression is the linearity in the logit. So once I got my model up and running I test for nonlinearity using Box-Tidwell test. One of my continuous predictors (X) has tested positive for nonlinearity. What am I suppose to do next?

As this is a violation of the assumptions shall I get rid of the predictor (X) or include the nonlinear transformation (X*X). Or transform the variable into a categorical?
If you have a reference could you please point me to that too?

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest to use restricted cubic splines (`rcs` in R, see the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) and [Design](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Design/index.html) packages for examples of use), instead of adding power of $X$ in your model. This approach is the one that is recommended by Frank Harrell, for instance, and you will find a nice illustration in his handouts (§2.5 and chap. 9) on *Regression Modeling Strategies* (see the [companion website](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/twiki/bin/view/Main/RmS)).

You can compare the results with your Box-Tidwell test by using the `boxTidwell()` in the [car](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) package.

Transforming continuous predictors into categorical ones is generally not a good idea, see e.g. [Problems Caused by Categorizing Continuous Variables](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous).

Answer (score 6):

It *may* be appropriate to include a nonlinear transformation of *x*, but probably not simply *x* × *x*, i.e x<sup>2</sup>. I believe you may find this a useful reference in determining which transformation to use:

G. E. P. Box and Paul W. Tidwell (1962). Transformation of the Independent Variables. *Technometrics* Volume 4 Number 4, pages 531-550. http://www.jstor.org/stable/1266288

Some consider the Box-Tidwell family of transformations to be *more* general than is often appropriate for interpretability and parsimony. Patrick Royston and Doug Altman introduced the term **fractional polynomials** for  Box-Tidwell transformations with simple rational powers in an influential 1994 paper:

P. Royston and D. G. Altman (1994). Regression using fractional polynomials of continuous covariates: parsimonious parametric modeling. *Applied Statistics* Volume 43: pages 429–467. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2986270

Patrick Royston in particular has continued to work and publish both papers and software on this, culminating in a book with Willi Sauerbrei:

P. Royston and W. Sauerbrei (2008). *Multivariable Model-building: A Pragmatic Approach to Regression Analysis Based on Fractional Polynomials for Modelling Continuous Variables*. Chichester, UK: Wiley. ISBN 978-0-470-02842-1

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget to check for interactions between X and other independent variables.  Leaving interactions unmodeled can make X look like it has a non-linear effect when it simply has a non-additive one.

Comment: Good point. I've only come across the converse: assuming an effect is linear when it isn't can lead to spurious statistical evidence for multiplicative interaction terms.

Comment: @onestop, do you have a reference about that? I believe it, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly why that would happen.