# Linearity predictor with log odds violated in binary logistic regression - How to solve?

Tags: r, binary-data, regression, logistic

When testing the assumption for linearity with the log odds in my binary logit model (using Box-Tidwell), I found that one of my predictors does not satisfy this assumption. What should I do next? Transform this predictor? In what way? And how to do that?

PS: I am using RStudio.

Comment: Your question may be already answered on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4058/28500). Also, see the many questions here related to [`data-transformation`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transformation). Your understanding of the subject matter should be the first source of suggestions about ways to transform predictor variables.